# req.headers.authorization coming back as undefined

Tags: graphql, apollo-server, express-graphql

I'm pretty new to graphql and apollo, and I'm working on a project where I need to be able to use `context` to get a variable for my query. The issue that I'm having is that my `context.user` is coming back null because my `req.headers.authorization` is  undefined. I'm unsure as to why this is happening as in my frontend

```
const authLink = setContext(async (_, { headers }) => {
  const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('token');
  try {
  if (token !== null) {
  return {
    headers: {
      ...headers,
      authorization: `Bearer ${token}` || null,
    }
   }
  }
}
catch (error) {
  throw error;
}
});
```

my token is not null and when I tested `` const auth: `Bearer ${token}` || null console.log(auth) `` after `if (token !== null) {` it came back with Bearer and my token value. Does anyone know why this is happening? I would really appreciate any help or advice. Thank you!

rest of frontend client.js

```
import { ApolloClient, split, createHttpLink, HttpLink, InMemoryCache } from '@apollo/client';
import { getMainDefinition } from '@apollo/client/utilities';
import { setContext } from "@apollo/client/link/context";
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
import { GraphQLWsLink } from "@apollo/client/link/subscriptions";
import { createClient } from "graphql-ws";

const wslink = new GraphQLWsLink(
  createClient({
    url: "ws://localhost:4000/subscriptions",
   /* connectionParams: {
      authToken: user.authToken,
    },*/
  }),
);


const httpLink = new HttpLink({
  uri: 'http://localhost:4000/graphql',
});


const authLink = setContext(async (_, { headers }) => {
  const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('token');
  try {
  if (token !== null) {
  return {
    headers: {
      ...headers,
      authorization: `Bearer ${token}` || null,
    }
   }
  }
}
catch (error) {
  throw error;
}
});


const splitLink = split(
  ({ query }) => {
    const definition = getMainDefinition(query);
    return (
      definition.kind === 'OperationDefinition' &&
      definition.operation === 'subscription'
    );
  },
  wslink,
  authLink.concat(httpLink)
);



export const client = new ApolloClient({
  link: splitLink,
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
});
```

backend index.js

```
import express from 'express';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import WebSocket from 'ws';
import { createServer } from 'http';
import { ApolloServer } from 'apollo-server-express';
import { makeExecutableSchema } from '@graphql-tools/schema';
import {
  ApolloServerPluginDrainHttpServer,
  ApolloServerPluginLandingPageLocalDefault,
} from "apollo-server-core";
import { useServer } from 'graphql-ws/lib/use/ws';
import constants from './config/constants.js';
import typeDefs from './graphql/schema.js';
import resolvers  from './graphql/resolvers/index.js';
import { decodeToken } from './services/auth.js';

const app = express();
const httpServer = createServer(app);
const schema = makeExecutableSchema({ typeDefs, resolvers });
const server = new ApolloServer({
  schema,
  context: ({ req }) => ({
    user: req.user
  }),
  csrfPrevention: true,
  cache: "bounded",
  plugins: [
     ApolloServerPluginDrainHttpServer({ httpServer }),
     {
       async serverWillStart() {
         return {
           async drainServer() {
             await serverCleanup.dispose();
           },
         };
       },
     },
    ApolloServerPluginLandingPageLocalDefault({ embed: true }),
  ],
});


const wsServer = new WebSocket.Server({
  server: httpServer,
  path: '/graphql',
});


const serverCleanup = useServer({ schema }, wsServer);

async function auth(req, res, next) { 
  try {
      const token = req.headers.authorization;
      //token is undefined Why???
      if (token != null) {
        const user = await decodeToken(token);
        req.user = user; // eslint-disable-line
      } 
      else {
        req.user = null; // eslint-disable-line
 
      }

      next();
    } catch (error) {
      throw error;
    }
  }
app.use(auth);
await server.start();
server.applyMiddleware({ app });


mongoose
  .connect(process.env.MONGODB_URL || 'mongodb://localhost/AMO', {
       useNewUrlParser: true, 
       useUnifiedTopology: true 
    })
  .then(() => {
    console.log("MongoDB Connected");
    return httpServer.listen(4000, () => {
      console.log(`Server ready at http://localhost:4000/graphql`);
    });
  })
```

Comment: FYI, `authorization: `Bearer ${token}` || null,` will never be `null` as the left side will aways have a value. Bearer something.

Comment: I don't understand `httpServer.listen()` vs. `app.listen()` I haven't wrapped my express app in http createServer before. Other than that it looks okay. Have you tried dumping all the header values to the console to see what there?